# How to get lsyncd to log error when dest drive fails?

Tags: rsync

I'm trying out `lsyncd` for the first time by following the steps detailed in this [article](https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/how-to-mirror-local-and-remote-directories-on-a-vps-with-lsyncd).

The files and sub-folders are sync-ed to another mounted drive. I then simulated a failed drive by unmounting the destination drive. Instead of reporting an error in the log file, lsyncd created another folder in `/mnt`.

I have 2 questions:

(1) How can I make `lsyncd` report an error instead of creating a new `dest` folder in `\mnt`?

(2) Is it possible to have a pop-up to report the failed drive?

Researching on the net did not yield much results. Hope experienced Linux and lsyncd users can enlighten. Thanks in advance!

My current config is:

```
settings{
    logfile = "/var/log/lsyncd/lsyncd.log",
    statusFile = "/var/log/lsyncd/lsyncd.status"
}

sync{
    default.rsync,
    source = "/source",
    target = "/mnt/tmp/dest",
    delay = 15
}
```

Answer (score 0):

In your example, your destination drive hasn't *failed*; from an OS perspective we still have a consistent good filesystem.

However, what you may need to do is to have an `onStartup` test that will check to see if the target directory already exists; if it does not then fail.  That will cause the sync to fail.

Details are here: http://axkibe.github.io/lsyncd/manual/config/layer3/

I haven't tested this but I would expect something like

```
onStartup = '[[ -d "^target" ]] || exit 2',
```

might do the job.

Comment: Thanks for your suggestion, @Stephen. I've tested, the onStartup addition works if the drive is not mounted on startup. Would it also work if the drive fails mid-way?

Comment: I just did a `umount` of the drive mid-way *after* the lsyncd service is started. Afraid it still has the issue, i.e. lsyncd `mkdir` a new folder at the mount point.